# Are Unbound's block and device radix sorts supported now?

Tags: aleagpu

Sort is not trivial to implement and I can't find the module in either documentation or the autocomplete. Is it not supported yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending Alea GPU with sorting primitives is still pending but in the pipeline. In the mean time you would need to implement your own sorting kernels.